# Are there any multiparty homomorphic encryption schemes?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation

Are there any multiparty homomorphic encryption schemes ?
Most of the literature is about two party schemes . 
Is there any generalization made for n party ?

Comment: thx i did not knew it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one I'm most familiar with is the [SPDZ protocol](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/535). The authors have implementing [AES via SPDZ](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/262) with up to 10 parties.